# How could I check if a player is exposed to rain?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was looking for a way to check if a player is exposed (no roof or anything) for a project and ended up thinking of one, but I failed to create it.

I found out that spreadplayer will tp the armorstand to the highest block on the xz cords and used Pos[1](y cord) with store to store the Y value.Then, i'd subtract the armorstand score to mine, so if it's **+**, then it's above, and bellow is **-**.Then, to prevente lag, it would take sometime to refresh and repeat the process.
But I found bug and can't find a way to fix it. The problem I stumbled upon was that if the armorstand is bellow,it would get a **-** score value and die as expected, but after 3 times of killing itself, it would emit a positive signal (even though the score displayed as always **-**) and trigger as if it were above me.

> World download: [World Download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IEa3OaexgHavF24jE8jrxNbeJwqvtIAj)
>    A little messed up but here is the chart: [Print](https://prnt.sc/p08hz9)

Since I'm looking foward to use it in Multiplayer, creating a unique armorstand to each player simultaneosly is pretty hard.
 I found out that spreadplayer will tp the armorstand to the highest block on the xz cords and used Pos[1](y cord) with store to store the Y value.Then, i'd subtract the armorstand score to mine, so if it's +, then it's above, and bellow is -.Then, to prevente lag, it would take sometime to refresh and repeat the process.

Comment: You could set fire at the player's location and check if the rain extinguishes it. But something tells me that that's not a good idea. ;)

Comment: Something is messed up with that archive, I can't get some of the files out of it. Here's the 7z output: https://pastebin.com/GbwGFNmH Maybe try packing it as zip without compression, that always works flawlessly for me on all devices. Or simply upload the folder to Google Drive, that automatically takes care of everything else.

Comment: I'm not sure on how to ping others, but here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IEa3OaexgHavF24jE8jrxNbeJwqvtIAj

Comment: You ping other users like this: @FabianRöling -- however I don't think a ping is necessary when only one user has commented on your question, as they are automatically notified.

Comment: Good to know since I was concerned you wouldn't get notificated.

Comment: You uploaded a superflat world with quartz and water and lava lakes. No datapacks, no command blocks.

Comment: Huh,, funny... tp to 0 60 0 That might work. I set worldspawn there but for some reason it didn't register (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest solution:

```
/execute as [selector] at @s if blocks ~ ~1 ~ ~ 255 ~ x y z all run scoreboard players set @s [name] 1
/execute as [selector] at @s unless blocks ~ ~1 ~ ~ 255 ~ x y z all run scoreboard players set @s [name] 0
```

Where `[name]` stands for the scoreboard name of your choice, `[selector]` is the player or entity you are looking to test for and `x y z` is a coordinate of the world where it should be all air(only the block of that coordinate and all above).
1 means he is exposed and 0 means he is in cover.

---

I had to do it again, and came back here since I found a [better solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/egwsin/detect_if_an_entity_has_sky_access/) since it uses recursion, is cheap and doesn't require any pre empty space. This only works with datapacks

In short, what it does is:

- Set player's Y score to his Y pos
- Add player's Y score by 1
- Check if block above him is air (Using positioned). If so, Go back to step 2

Note here that using positioned will slowly move the referencial pos up, instead of using the player's initial pos.

Let us create the scoreboard:

```
/scoreboard objectives add y dummy
```

In a file, let us call it main.mcfunction, do:

```
## Reset tag
tag @s remove exposed

## Do the recursive function
# Save player's y pos into the score
execute store result score @s y run data get entity @s Pos[1]
execute as @s at @s run function <namespace:our_rec_function>

# Tag player if is exposed to sky
execute if score @s y_trace matches 255 run tag @s add exposed
```

And our <our_rec_function.mcfunction> file will have:

```
scoreboard players add @s y 1
execute if score @s y matches ..254 positioned ~ ~1 ~ if block ~ ~ ~ air run function <namespace:our_rec_function>
```

Really clever solution, and really compact. Love it!

Simply change the `function <namespace:function>` to the appropriate names based on your file structure.

Comment: Why those coordinates 25, 31, 10? What is significant about them?

Comment: This is an old answer but i assume these numbers were supposed to be x y and z. These were the coordinates on my world that `it should be all air` (Edited post)

Comment: Shouldn't one of them be `unless`, specifically, the bottom one? Logically, if the blocks above are not air, it should be set to 0, hence using `unless` instead of `if`.

Comment: You are rigth. I'm not sure how i screwed up copying and pasting it... I belive I don't have the world anymore to check nor the game to try and figure out the right answer. I'll leave it as unless as it seems it would work.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to detect this on a multiplayer server, I would create a plugin, whichs checks, if it's raining (by getting the weather of the world of the player) and if the weather is actually affecting the biome at the players location (e.g. there is no rain in the desert). If this all is given and the block below the player is also the highest block at the players location, then the player is 'affected' of the rain.

Comment: I'm more focoused in command block, as I usually play by myself. It's more about the challenge in doing it so rather then the result. I'll take a look into some plugins, but I've never used any. Also, would you be able to transfer these info (raining and exposed) to a command block?

Comment: Oh okay, didn't got this - sorry. No, I'm not thaaat familiar with command blocks to transfer this logic to command blocks.