# How can I allow Riptide to be combined with Channeling and Loyalty?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

Title contains the core of it. The way I imagine it to work is:

- When not in water/rain, instead of blocking you from throwing the trident, Riptide has no effect.
- Riptide, when actually used, negates the effects of Channeling (and Loyalty since Riptide pretty much does that anyway). So when in water/rain, only the Riptide effect is applied. Otherwise, Channeling and Loyalty are applied.

While at it, several other enchantment patches (such as Smite and Bane of the Anthropods being compatible with and applied instead of lower-level Sharpness, and/or a similar approach for the Protection enchantments) would be appreciated, Riptide/Channeling/Loyalty is the top priority business for me though.

Whether through commands or a mod, I'll settle for any way if I have to. I'm no fan of inventing the wheel though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've developed a data pack that allows Riptide, Channeling, and Loyalty to be combined together. Anvils will work to combine Riptide but only when you are not in rain and Riptide is applied first; enchantment tables won't apply them together though.

The data pack is downloadable [here](https://github.com/ExpertCoder14/mc-trident-enchantments).

## Concepts used

- I used commands from [Bruno Rodrigues's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/359878/250180) to detect the weather. If you look at the function files, the commands will summon an armour stand at (0, 255, 0) and check the weather using it.

  ```
  summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invulnerable:1b,Invisible:1b,Fire:32766s,CustomName:'"rain"'}
  ```

  ```
  execute as @e[limit=1,name=rain,nbt={Fire:0s}] at @s run scoreboard players set $rain trident_inRain 3
  execute as @e[limit=1,name=rain,nbt={Fire:0s}] at @s run data modify entity @s Fire set value 30000
  execute as @e[name=rain] if score $rain trident_inRain matches 1.. run scoreboard players remove $rain trident_inRain 1
  ```
- I used another answer from [Bruno Rodrigues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/357278/250180) to check if the player is exposed to rain. This technique involves checking to see if all blocks above you are air. I set commands to cut a hole at column (0, 0), and then tested for players with that:

  ```
  fill 0 2 0 0 255 0 minecraft:air
  ```

  ```
  execute as @a at @s if blocks ~ ~1 ~ ~ 255 ~ 0 2 0 all run ...
  ```
- I used [a technique](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/372238/250180) that displays fake `CanPlaceOn`/`CanDestroy` data on items through the item's lore, and modified it to display fake enchantments instead. When a user is not in the rain, the Riptide enchantment is removed from the enchantments list and a fake Riptide enchantment is added via the lore.
- I used [player inventory modification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/376905/250180) in order to modify player inventory data. This involves a special loot table, downloadable [here](https://github.com/MinecraftPhi/MinecraftPhi-modules/blob/master/phi.modifyinv/src/datapack/data/minecraft/loot_tables/blocks/yellow_shulker_box.json).

  ```
  loot replace entity @p hotbar.0 1 mine 0 0 0 stick{drop_contents:1b}
  ```

If you experience any problems with this data pack, please create an issue on GitHub instead of commenting below!

Comment: That's really cool! The way this uses functions to completely replace and mimic MineCraft functionality reminds me of the datapacks by TheDiamondPlayables, in particular Blacksmithing. Definitely trying this out, even though I'll probably still also make my own mod because the concept I had is kind of interesting.

Comment: By the way, based on how it works, it actually should allow combining Riptide with Loyalty and Channeling on an anvil - as long as you apply Riptide first (and don't happen to be in the rain or in a water pool while using the anvil for Loyalty and Channeling).

Comment: UPDATE: Tried it out, it works. With the datapack enabled (and properly initialized), you can enchant Tridents with Loyalty on an anvil even if they have (fake) Riptide.

Comment: With the predicate update, the detect weather is now deprecated! (Of course, as long as you are in the right version) You can check this generator (https://misode.github.io/predicate/) or the wiki page (https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Predicate)

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues Already knew of that! Planned for the next update.